# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Out of memory

Tags: java, out-of-memory, tibco

we are using TIBCO integration manager from a while in company but from few months experiencing out of memory issue in the process which only gets fixed when it gets restarted. Below are errors which we are receiving in our logs.

```
2017 Oct 04 02:33:40:090 GMT -4 TIBIM.5.0.2V34-HOTFIX11.SV_IM_RVCMQengine1 Error [IM_TASK] AEIM-200191
java.lang.Exception: Out of memory at com.tibco.share.bus.BusTibrvCmTransport.send(BusTibrvCmTransport.java:264)
    at com.tibco.share.bus.Bus.send(Bus.java:420)
    at  com.tibco.im.fw.task.AEAdapterObjSendTask.eval(AEAdapterObjSendTask.java:226)
    at com.tibco.im.wf.Job.step(Job.java:986)
    at com.tibco.im.wf.Job.checkStep(Job.java:822)
    at com.tibco.im.wf.NewJobDispatcher$JobCourier.runx(NewJobDispatcher.java:240)
    at com.tibco.im.wf.NewJobDispatcher$JobCourier.run(NewJobDispatcher.java:207)


 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested 12 bytes for CHeapObj-new. Out of swap space?

Internal Error (allocation.inline.hpp:39), pid=23296, tid=1797974928 #  Error: CHeapObj-new # # JRE version: 6.0_18-b07 # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode linux-x86 ) # An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /usr/tibco/prod/apps/SV/imcentral/hs_err_pid23296.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Current JVM is set to below sizes

## JVM

> java.extended.properties -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m

## Virtual Memory

$ulimit -d -v

> data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
>
> virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 37748736

## Memory On Server

$free -g

```
             total      used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem           62         55          7          0          1         16
-/+ buffers/cache:        36         25
 Swap:         15          1         14
```

## Server OS:

> Linux simtcuap0014 2.6.18-274.el5 #1 SMP Fri Jul 8 17:36:59 EDT 2011
>   x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Have tried increasing the Virtual memory, also adjusted JVM size in the config but nothing helped till now.
Could you please suggest any other method for it.

Comment: *"Could you please suggest any other method for it"* Yes. Contact Tibco and tell them to fix the memory leak.

Comment: Restart it once a day via a cron job.

Comment: Servers that accumulate space consumption because of memory leaks are very annoying. Besides finding the leak and notifying the responsible people you should indeed counter the problem by simply restarting the server every once in a while. This can easily be done with a **cron-job** as already suggested. This is a routine which triggers other given programs (for example your restart-program) at set times (for example once a day at 4 o'clock in the morning).

Comment: I think that you have two solutions. 1 - cut the layer/ component / program in two or create a rule in hawk for restart the service.